# How can I take portrait pictures like Apple's 30 years of Mac campaign?

Tags: post-processing, portrait, technique

Is it possible just by getting a good camera? Do I have to do serious editing after the photo is taken? http://www.apple.com/30-years/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which photos do you mean?  The ones that have the reflection underneath are likely touched up a little, but proper lighting, a fast lens and a decent camera with a reasonably large sensor is all that is necessary for most of the images I saw in the start of that video anyway.

You need a fast lens and a relatively decent size sensor (APS-c or bigger most likely) to get the really shallow depth of field on the macro shots of the circuits and such.  You need even lighting and a black backdrop that you can keep in shadows to get the strong black background behind the image.

The reflection can be accomplished in the real world using glass or something similar, but it's easier just to do in post most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

Lots and lots of studio lighting and modifiers. It is all in this article. [The illusion of simplicity: Photographer Peter Belanger on shooting for Apple](http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/8/4311868/the-illusion-of-simplicity-photographer-peter-belanger-on-shooting).

[image: sample]